# Http request to the call to API not working in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

When I try to fetch some data from weather API using `fetch` request in React application its not getting the response from the api below are the code which I wrote:

```
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            datatemp: {},
            loading:true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        loading:true;
        fetch('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({
                datatemp: data,
                loading: false
            });
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log(this.state.datatemp);

        return (
            <p>ddd</p>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

all the help will be much appreciable.

Comment: Try to console.log the response from the request. like so `.then(data => {console.log(data); ...}`

Comment: Hi Toan i tried your method even though its throwing an empty array. but t api url is working fine

Comment: Did you check your url ? I got 404 error

Comment: In the callback you set to field `dataTemp` in state but in render function you console log `datatemp`. Btw, there are some tools which allow you to format your code to make it more clear such as: ESLint, Prettier, .. that really useful for you for sure

Comment: Hi Dostinbek, yes it will return 404 responce array. but that also in request iam not getting

Comment: Hi Toan i did the same which you told still iam getting an empty array as response

Comment: It's because of CORS errors. You can't access the data of this API directly from client-side. check your console to see this error.

Comment: I have provided clean working code with another url. Just check it bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look bro I have changed url to test! Just check it**

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      datatemp: {},
      loading: true
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.fetchedData(data);
      });
  }

  fetchedData = data => {
    this.setState({
      datatemp: data,
      loading: false
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.datatemp.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.datatemp[i].body);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <p>Good Luck</p>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: check your url. Because it is working with another url

Comment: Chears!! seems its working. one more question Dostonbek, how can i take all  body attribute elements from the api which you gave.

Comment: I have edited my answer in a way that you want bro. Check it out

Comment: Thank you so much broo. :) its really helpful for me. I appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of CORS.

Try replacing your API with any Dummy API which Doesn't Restrict CORS. for Example:
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

```js
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            datatemp: {},
            loading: true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    dataTemp: data,
                    loading: false
                }, () => {
                    console.log("data: ", this.state.dataTemp);
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p>ddd</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the function of `loading:true;` Remove it your code works

```
import React from 'react'

    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                datatemp: {},
                loading:true
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {

            fetch('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    datatemp: data,
                    loading: false
                });
            });
        }

        render()
        {
            console.log(this.state.datatemp);

            return (
                <p>ddd</p>
            )
        }
    }
    export default App;
```